# Hibernate- One to Many Mapping - save relation mapping but not the nested Entity

Tags: hibernate, entity, one-to-many

I have Entity A(Role) having OneToMany relationship to Entity B(Functions), when I am trying to save A, when I run it first time everything works well, next time when I want to add new role with some of functions, I get error as UNIQUE constraint as there are already records in Functions entity.

How can I save just mapping between A & B if records are already available in B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use a `@ManyToMany` mapping.